# I cannot figure out a way to keep track of words guessed already

Tags: python

I have this program that tries to guess the input word by using a for loop to randomly choose a letter in an array. My only problem is that I need a way to keep track of words already output by the program, and then omit them from being guessed again.

```
import random
# This is the password to crack
user_pass = input("Enter your password: ")
# This is the array that the random module pulls from
password = ['A','B','C','D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

guess = ""

# This while loop runs random combinations of numbers from the array until the output equals user_pass
while (guess != user_pass):
  guess = ""
  for letter in range(len(user_pass)):
    guess_letter = password[random.randint(0, 25)]
    guess = str(guess_letter) + str(guess)
    
  print(guess)
  

    
# printing the matched password
print("Your password is: " + guess)
```

Comment: Use a list or a set to store the guessed words and check each word if it's there...

Comment: Can you not create an empty list outside of the loop and store the guesses in that and then check against the list each time?

Comment: Just as a side, note: Python's random library uses the Mersenne Twister engine which has a period of 2^19937 - 1. In other words, the chances you actually see a repeat permutation of letters is really little.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your previous guesses in a `set` so you can check each new random guess against it.  You can also simplify the process of generating guesses by using `str.join` with `random.choices`:

```
import random
import string

user_pass = input("Enter your password: ")
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

guesses = set()
while True:
    guess = ''.join(random.choices(chars, k=len(user_pass)))
    if guess in guesses:
        continue
    print(guess)
    guesses.add(guess)
    if guess == user_pass:
        break

print(f"Your password is:  {guess}")
```

Another approach is to simply iterate through all possible passwords deterministically (e.g. alphabetically) rather than randomly; that way you don't have to keep track of prior guesses since you're automatically guaranteed to never repeat a guess.

```
import itertools
import string

user_pass = input("Enter your password: ")
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

for p in itertools.product(chars, repeat=len(user_pass)):
    guess = ''.join(p)
    print(guess)
    if guess == user_pass:
        break

print(f"Your password is:  {guess}")
```

Compared to random guessing, the second version of the above code will be much faster to guess passwords that are "earlier" (e.g. if they start with "A") and much slower to guess ones that are "later" (e.g. if they start with "Z").  Averaged over a large number of completely random passwords, or over all possible passwords, the two approaches should take a roughly equal number of guesses.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
# This is the password to crack
user_pass = input("Enter your password: ")
# This is the array that the random module pulls from
password = ['A','B','C','D','E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

guess = ""
user_pass = user_pass.lower()
# This while loop runs random combinations of numbers from the array until the output equals user_pass

for letter in range(len(user_pass)):
    guess_letter = password[random.randint(0, 25)]
    guess_letter = guess_letter.lower()
    while guess_letter != user_pass[letter]:
        guess_letter = password[random.randint(0,25)]
        guess_letter = guess_letter.lower()
    guess += guess_letter
  
# printing the password
print("Your password is: " + guess)
```

Here this can guess the password.

Comment: This doesn't address OP's question of how to avoid repeats, and it doesn't even "guess" the password in the way that OP was trying to do it; it's peeking at each letter as it goes.  It also lowercases the output for no reason.